# How to fix AS3 TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Skool_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[Skool_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:10]
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at Skool_fla::MainTimeline/goback()[Skool_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:22]
```

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

This is my code for both the frames:

Frame 1: This is the main menu screen where you can access the credit section

```
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//setting up the variables
//events
//stop the timeline

stop();

//the play button
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playani);
function playani(e:MouseEvent)
{
    //asking it to progress to the load menu
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
//the credits button

credit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, creditslide);
function creditslide(e:MouseEvent)
{
    //asking it to go the credits frame
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Frame 2: This is where the credits appear

```
    //
//
//all the imports

//events

var credit:credits_bck = new credits_bck ();
var credits_name: credit_nm = new credit_nm ();
var back_butn: back_button = new back_button ();
addChild (credit);
addChild (credits_name);
addChild (back_butn);

back_butn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goback);

function goback(G:MouseEvent)
{

removeChild (credit);
removeChild (credits_name);

gotoAndStop(1);

}
```

Comment: well i am getting this error why is it that? and how can I fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `play_btn` or `back_butn` is null.  Your error message's line numbers don't correspond to your code so it's hard to say.  But the gist is you're trying to access a property of something that *isn't anything*.  Check to make sure you're initializing your variables/references properly.

Comment: ummm right...is there any way to check if it's null? the play_btn worked fine before i used addChild function for the back_btn instead of just placing it on the stage...

Comment: From the stack trace you posted, the error appears to occur when you're on frame 2 and click the "go back" button. When it goes back to frame 1, something (perhaps play_btn or credit_btn) is null. The stack trace says the error happens on Frame 1, line #10. Look there to see what it's referring to.

Comment: @user1932905, based on your edit, line #10 seems to be: `play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playani);`

Comment: @user1932905 That would be one solution, but I'm guessing may be a better one. I normally program in Flex ... I don't understand why it's there the first time around, but not when you go back to frame 1 ... are you removing it? If so, yes, just add it back. If you're not removing it, it would be good to understand why it's going away :)

Comment: Thx a lot guys for answering the question... I got it fixed.. the problem was I had another button with the exact same name as back button...lool really stupid of me...but oh well i leaned something from it.. thx sunil U seem to be helping me a lot in all my questions :D and thx Madbreaks for pointing out the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is Flash bug too.

In my FLA there was a layer with one empty keyframe. If I puted a vector graphics on it, the error was gone. If there was one or multiple MovieClips and there was no vector graphic - the error was there again.

Then I made a new layer and copy pasted all the objects from damaged layer to new and deleted the damaged layer. It solved the problem.
NOTE: Don't copy the keyframes. Only copy the contents.

Now my project is much more complicated and sadly the error came back again.

Test movie frequently and if the error comes back, check the last keyframes and layers you created.